# Download a selected file from my GridView using DoubleClick

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to download a file that I uploaded into my GridView. Each time I double click on the second document in the GridView, it opens the first uploaded document and saves it

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub dgDocuments_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Handles dgDocuments.DoubleClick

    LoadUploadedDocuments()

    Try
        Dim objTransactionDocument As Objects.TransactionsDocuments
        If dgDocuments.CurrentRowIndex.Equals(-1) Then
            Dim obj As Object = dgDocuments.Item(dgDocuments.CurrentRowIndex, 1)
            objTransactionDocument = Managers.TransactionsDocuments.SelectTransactionsDocuments(Convert.ToInt32(obj))
        End If

        If Not objTransactionDocument Is Nothing Then
            If objTransactionDocument.TransactionsDocumentsID = 1 Then
                Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog
                saveFile.FileName = objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.Substring(objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.LastIndexOf("\"))
                saveFile.Title = "Download supporting document to transaction " + m_objTransaction.TransactionID.ToString()


                If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    Dim saveDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFile.FileName)
                    Dim name As String = objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.Substring(objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.LastIndexOf("\"))
                    Dim saveLocation As String = saveDir + name
                    System.IO.File.Copy(objTransactionDocument.FileLocation, saveLocation)
                    MessageBox.Show("Document saved successfully")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Document saved unsuccessfully " + ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add / to saveDir as

```
saveDir+='/'
```

Comment: How? Show please

Comment: If saveFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                    Dim saveDir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFile.FileName)
                    Dim name As String = objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.Substring(objTransactionDocument.FileLocation.LastIndexOf("\"))
                    Dim saveLocation As String = saveDir  & "/"  & name
                    System.IO.File.Copy(objTransactionDocument.FileLocation, saveLocation)
                    MessageBox.Show("Document saved successfully")
                End If